# How do I get my client to focus when he wants to do only more?

Tags: client, selling-ux

I am facing a classic situation where my client has drawn a gigantic mindmap with branching nodes and trees and given it to me for scoping out the project he wants built,

Now I know that 80 percent of what he wants to build is redundant and I have made the case that only by focussing on the 20 percent can we build a successful online product that his customers will actually use.

But he insists that he has more to offer and he wants his customers to do more with his product. I am trying to convince him that his customers really want to solve their problems first before they engage on other levels. My biggest concern is that his decisions will end up negatively impacting the essential workflows I am building.

He does not have the time or resources for user testing so I really don't know how to convince him about the harm that will come out of his decisions.

How can I get him to focus on core task flows rather than build superflous architecture which I know no one will use.

Answer (score 3):

How about using straight persuasion tools: price and time?

Also you can try "symmentrical answer" by creating mindmap containing your vision, advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Yes I am creating my own mindmap but how do I persuade him ideologically - he has to convince internal stakeholders and I need to make sure I am building the right thing for his customers. Twisted nature of our priorities I am talking about.

Comment: So price and time would be a good strategy too - but could you elaborate on what you mean by 'using them as a straight persuasion tool'?

Comment: I mean money, time and gun (joke) are stuff that persuade without long explanation, i.e. straight.